# How does GTK theming work?

Tags: gnome, themes, gtk

Running 22.04 LTS. I have installed gnome-extensions and gnome-tweaks, and I can get various applications as well as the GNOME shell to change their appearance. However, not all applications or windows respect the changes to the themes. For instance, nautilus just seems to use some kind of a default theme, as does "Ubuntu software". Is this expected behavior for those particular applications? Is there any way to have all desktop apps apply the GTK theme?